# How to select biggest zip code for each country

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, greatest-n-per-group, lateral-join

> In each country, which city has the highest ZIP code?
> Select only the Country name, and the city name

Here is a graphic schema, which may help you:

[image]

This is what I done so far:

```
SELECT CountryName, CityName
from City ci
join County co on co.CountryID = ci.CountryID
group by CountryName, CityName, ci.ZipCode
having ZipCode = MAX(ZipCode)
```

I would be grateful if someone can solve me this.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MS Access? Please remove one of the tags. Please also show (in text format not images) some sample data and expected results.

Comment: SQL Server ( Transact-SQL)

Comment: I would try removing the ci.zipcode from the GROUP BY clause because you are trying to find the max. If you include it in GROUP BY you will get all the zipcodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a lateral join:

```
select co.countryname, ci.cityname, ci.zipcode
from country co
cross apply (
    select top (1) with ties ci.* 
    from city ci 
    where ci.countryid = co.countryid
    order by ci.zipcode desc
) ci
```

You can also use `row_number()`:

```
select co.countryname, ci.cityname, ci.zipcode
from country co
inner join (
    select ci.*, rank() over(partition by countryid order by zipcode desc) rn
    from city ci
) ci on ci.countryid = co.countryid
```

If you are running MS Access, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select co.countryname, ci.cityname, ci.zipcode
from country co as co
inner join city as ci on ci.countryid = co.countryid
where ci.zipcode = (
    select max(c1.zipcode)
    from city as ci1
    where ci1.countryid = ci.country
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. Use rank fuction and fiter it in outer query

```
select * from
(select c1.countryname as countryname, c2.cityname as cityname, 
max_city_zip = rank() Over (partition by c1.countryname order by c2.cityname desc)
from country c1
inner join city c2
on c1.countryID = c2.countryID
group by c1.countryname, c2.cityname)Y where max_city_zip = 1
```